# Shiny app can't find an attribute in my dataset

Tags: r, shiny

I am plotting some attributes of my dataset. I have a weird issue: I have worked on my dataset for days and it all worked. Now I have put some parts of my work (the grafic parts) on a shiny app. 
It is not working and gives me an error: he can't fine one of the attributes I have. But it can find the other two from the same db.

Error: ** Warning: Error in reorder: object "CompanyLocation" not found **

Can you help me please?

Edit: I have three plots. They have Identical code (I only changed the attributes), but only 2/3 are working. Here is the code of the not working one (server part).

```
library(dplyr)
singleLocation <- group_by(chocolate, CompanyLocation)
ratingLocation <- summarise(singleLocation,  count=n(), ratingMedio=mean(Rating))
locationDesc<- arrange(ratingLocation, desc(ratingMedio))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(locationDesc,aes(x=reorder(CompanyLocation, ratingMedio), y=ratingMedio)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=count, colour=factor(ratingMedio)), alpha=1/2) + theme(
  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1) , legend.position="none") + 
  labs(x="Country", y="Chocolate Rating", main="Company Location & Rating")
```

Comment: We would like to help you but that is impossible with the information you're giving us. I understand that your code confuses you right now and you do not know how to give us something concrete. Please read this post that gives directions about what you can do and how you can help us help you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for

Comment: @Jan is this ok?

Comment: Certainly a step into the right direction. What you need to do now is trying to narrow it down. I can only give you some directions. The message says that the `reorder` function does not recognize `CompanyLocation`. I hypothesize that you show two blocks of code that come from two different locations in your app. Is that correct. If I am right you have to look for what happens to `CompanyLocation`between the first and second block. If not, I am as puzlled as you are. Long story short: you need to narrow the location of the problem further down.

Comment: It is in the server part of the file, the code can get two attributes from my dataset, but not "CompanyLocation" (which is right there too)